Calculate opening and closing balance with running balance using three tables
I have three tables: Table 1 contains the data of each account opening balance with opening date and acct type
Table Name :    LedgerMaster



nID(pk)IDENTITY(1,1)
LEDGERACCTID
LEDGERACCTNAME
ACCTTYPE
OPENINGDATE
OPENINGBALANCE




1
101
CASHACCT
DEBIT
2024-01-01
10000


2
102
BANKACCT157
DEBIT
2024-01-01
0


3
201
VENDOR1
CREDIT
2024-01-01
2000


4
202
VENDOR2
CREDIT
2024-01-01
0


5
411
Sales Revenue
CREDIT
2024-01-01
0



Table 2: CreditMaster
this table contains all the daily credit transactions



nID
date
invoiceno
ledgerid
ledgername
cramount
description




1
2024-01-01
inv-01
411
Sales Revenue
2000
sale


2
2024-01-01
inv-02
411
Sales Revenue
1000
sales


3
2024-01-02
Inv-03
411
Sales Revenue
3000
sale


4
2024-01-01
PO-01
202
VENDOR1
1700
PURCHASE


5
2024-01-02
PO-02
202
VENDOR1
2000
PURCHASE


6
2024-01-01
inv-04
411
Sales Revenue
2500
sale


7
2024-01-02
inv-05
411
Sales Revenue
1500
sale


8
2024-01-01
PAY-01
101
CASHACCT
5000
Payment



Table 3 : DebitMaster



nID
date
invocieno
ledgerid
ledgername
dramount
description




1
2024-01-01
inv-01
101
CASHACCT
2000
sale


2
2024-01-01
inv-02
101
CASHACCT
1000
sale


3
2024-01-01
inv-03
101
CASHACCT
3000
sale


4
2024-01-01
inv-04
102
BANKACCT157
2500
sale


5
2024-01-02
inv-05
102
BANKACCT157
1500
sale


6
2024-01-01
PO-01
412
PurchaseAcct
5000
Purchase


7
2024-01-01
PAY-01
202
VENDOR
5000
PAYMENT



Expectation for example if I select the cashaaact(101) and date range like I select account and date from >=2024-01-01 and dateto<=2024-01-01



NID
iNVOICENO
DATE
DEBIT
CREDIT
BALANCE
DESCRIPTION

header 1
header 2





oPENING BALANCE
2024-01-01
1000
00
10000
OPENING BALANCE

cell 1
cell 2



INV-01
2024-01-01
2000
00
12000
SALE

cell 3
cell 4



inv-02
2024-01-01
1000
00
13000
SALE






PAY-01
2024-01-01
00
5000
8000
PAYMENT






When I change the date the opening balance will be become  8000 on 2024-01-02
If the account type is credit the opening balance will add on credit side and if accounttype is debit os opening balance will adsd on debit side
I do not have any idea how to do that using sql server query

Please edit your question to remove the excess use of CAPITALIZATION.

DON'T SCREAM. That's what all caps means

This fiddle might help us collaborate on a solution https://dbfiddle.uk/WOAimQWt

@SamHasan Please ensure your question's examples include all the required behaviour. Especially clarifications you've made in comments to answers below.

For this solution I union all 3 tables together and give them each a type.
I can then use CASE to control how each column behaves for the main select.
A  "SUM(amount) OVER.." will calculate the running sum.
SELECT nID, 
  
     invno, 
  
     date, 
  
  CASE TYPE 
  WHEN ' CREDIT' THEN ABS(amount) 
  ELSE 0.00 END as Credit,
  
  CASE TYPE 
  WHEN 'DEBIT' THEN ABS(amount)
  ELSE 0.00 END as Debit,  

   SUM(amount) OVER(ORDER BY date, TYPE desc 
     ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
          AS Balance,
  
     Description
FROM
  (
    SELECT nID, OPENINGDATE as date, 'oPENING BALANCE' as invno, LEDGERACCTID as ledgerid, LEDGERACCTNAME as ledgername, 'OPEN' as TYPE, OPENINGBALANCE as amount, 'OPENING balance' as description
    FROM LedgerMaster
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT nID, date, invoiceno as invno, ledgerid, ledgername, ' CREDIT' as TYPE, -cramount as amount, description 
    FROM CreditMaster
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT  nID, date, invocieno as invno, ledgerid, ledgername, 'DEBIT' as TYPE, dramount as amount, description 
    FROM DebitMaster
  ) CD 
WHERE ledgerid='101'
AND DATE BETWEEN   '2024-01-01' AND '2024-02-02'
ORDER BY DATE, TYPE desc 

fiddle



nID
invno
date
Credit
Debit
Balance
Description




1
oPENINGBALANCE
2024-01-01
0.00
0.00
10000
OPENINGbalance


1
inv-01
2024-01-01
0.00
2000.00
12000
sale


2
inv-02
2024-01-01
0.00
1000.00
13000
sale


3
inv-03
2024-01-01
0.00
3000.00
16000
sale


8
PAY-01
2024-01-01
5000.00
0.00
11000
Payment




Hi..thank you so much for your help..one thing i would like to ask and metion over here when amount is debit it should be add into the balance if the acctype is DEBIT AND IF THE ACCOUNT TYPE IS CREDIT THE CREDIT AMOUNT WILL ADD AT CREDIT SIDE.IN YOPU ABOE QUERY DEBIT AMOUNT IS SUBTRATCTING FROM BALANCE. ITS CASHACCT WHEN SALE IS HAPPEN VIA CASH  THE CASHACCT WILL BE DEBITOR AND IT WILL BE DO ADDITION WITH BALANCE AND WHEN CASH ACCT WILL CREDIT TI WILL DO SUNSTRACTION FROM BALANCE...I HOPE YOU UNDERSTAND WHAT I MEAN..MAY  DID NOT EXPLAIN WELL..THAN  YOU SO MUCH

Ordering by date when all the dates are the same? That's non deterministic, there is no guarantee they'll be processed in the order you want.

@SamHasan STOP SCREAMING!

@Sam Hasan  Query updated to add debit and subtract credit from balance. Also added sorting by type

OK..SORRY TO SAY BUT WHEN I CHANGE THE DATE THE CLOSING BALANCE SHOULD BE BECOME AS OPENING BALANCE ON NEXT DATE.. BT WHEN ICHANGE IT ITS NOT SHOWING THE OPENING BALANCE.. IAM SORRY IF I WRONG

@SamHasan PLEASE STOP SCREAMING!

@Sam Hasan Please provide an example of the table when they date range is incremented to 2024-01-02

Hi...@Bart McEndree
how i can share here my tables scripts with some data.....!

@Sam Hasan  Just make your changes to the fiddle and when you run it a new URL is generated. Paste that new URL here in the comments for everyone to see.

https://dbfiddle.uk/bZ15MH99  KINDLY CHECK SQL QUERY..WHEN I SELECT 2024-01-01 ITS SHOW OPENING BALANCE FOR ACCT 101(CASHAAACT) WHEN ICHANGEW THE DATE 2024-01-02 THE OPENING BALANCE NOT SHOWING..

https://dbfiddle.uk/bZ15MH99  Kindly check the query..when i use date 2024-01-01 then opening balance with credit ,debit and balance is showing..bt when i change the date opening balance not showing...for instance if the if i select the date 2024-01-01 and  acct 101(Accttype-debit) so opening balance will show and do addition with debit and balance..when i select acctype credit its add with credit side and substract with debit side vice versa.....closing balance of 2024-01-01 will become the opening balance on next dates(2024-01-02)..

You could hardcode it if there is no OPENINGDATE for 2024-01-02. https://dbfiddle.uk/kbIOWyXr    Maybe replace that part of the query with a table-valued function that ensures you have an opening date record or calculates one.

Hi..@Bart McEndree opening date is defined in ledgermaster table and via each day transection and query calculation on each date qopneing balance will be change.(closing balance will become the opening balance on next date)..correct me if i am wrong..thank you sir

Hi..@Bart McEndree  in your qeury its hardcoded ..but its the opening balance will be change on date change ..closing balance of previous date will be become the opening balance of next date..and according to this transection will start credit and debit and blanace...

@Sam Hasan If you will be doing daily updates of the data then it should work without  hardcoding or a function. To demonstrate that you would need to include your data update steps in the scirpt. I cannot put anymore work on this problem. Others need help.  Good luck.
